# Google spreadsheed API with Sencha Touch Ext.List

Tags: json, sencha-touch-2, google-sheets-api

I am using Sencha touch 2.1 to build a mobile app. I am trying to load a google spreadsheet as a datasource for a list.

I have made the google spreadsheet public you can find it at this link:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AhW0xtL9j2bAdHlwRE1qcE1WdDVLa2dRdDBxNTJBV0E&output=html

However I am not able to get it working.

Here is the code I have so far:

**The Model**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.InfoList', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    config: {
        fields: [
            'Title',
            'Description',
            'Icon'
        ],
        idProperty: '_id'
    }
});
```

**The Store**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.InfoList', {
extend : 'Ext.data.Store',

config : {
    model : 'MyApp.model.InfoList',
    proxy: {
        type: 'jsonp',
         url :  'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/0AhW0xtL9j2bAdHlwRE1qcE1WdDVLa2dRdDBxNTJBV0E/od6/public/basic?alt=json-in-script',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'feed.entry'
        }
    }

}
});
```

**The View**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.home.infolist', {
    extend : 'Ext.List',
    xtype : 'infoListView',
    disableSelection: true,
    config : {
        title : 'Info List',
        itemTpl: [
                    '<div class="itemInfo">',
                        '<div class="iconDiv">',
                            '<img src="{Icon}" class="icon"/>',
                        '</div>', 
                        '<div class="descriptionDiv">',
                            '<div class="title">{Title}</div>',
                            '<div class="description">{Description}</div>',
                        '</div>',
                        '<div class="disclosureDiv">',
                            '<img src="images/infoListDisclosure.png" class="iconImage"/>',
                        '</div>',
                        '<div class="clear"></div>',
                     '</div>',
                ].join(''),
        store : 'InfoList'
    }
});
```

The list is always empty. And if I use jsonp instead of json in the proxy the app stop running.

Is there a way to see what is the responce I get from the proxy in an alert? or any indications for what might be the problem is appreciated

PS: I building the application on IBM Worklight, but I am using sencha for the codings. I'm not sure if that affects anything

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attributes in JSON response are all lowercase like 'title' & 'content' whereas your model field names have first letter in uppercase like 'Title' & 'Description'. Moreover there is no field like 'Description' in JSON, its 'content' and also'title' data is in '$t' attribute.

I'd suggest you to dump and look at parsed JSON object in console to understand how to render its attribute correctly.

One more thing, instead of using:

https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/0AhW0xtL9j2bAdHlwRE1qcE1WdDVLa2dRdDBxNTJBV0E/od6/public/basic?alt=json-in-script

use this:

https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/0AhW0xtL9j2bAdHlwRE1qcE1WdDVLa2dRdDBxNTJBV0E/od6/public/values?alt=json-in-script

to get columns as attributes of `entry` object. In this case you can define your model like this:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.InfoList', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    config: {
        fields: [
            {name : 'id',type : 'string', mapping:'id.$t'},
            {name : 'Title',type : 'string', mapping:'gsx$Title.$t'},
            {name : 'Description',type : 'string', mapping:'gsx$Description.$t'},
            {name : 'Icon',type : 'string', mapping:'gsx$Icon.$t'}
        ],
        idProperty: 'id'
    }
});
```